# Error loading ActionBarSherlocks' demos on Eclipse

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library, android-compatibility, fragmenttransaction

I tried to load the demos on ActionBarSherlock but I'm getting an error on its Activities using `FragmentTransaction`. The activities are `FeatureToggles` and `TabNavigation`. I'm also getting an error on `TabNavigationCollapsed` because it's extending `TabNavigation` which uses `FragmentTransaction`.

The error is:

```
The import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved
```

What could be my error? My Project Build Target is Android 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there added Android support library in Build Path?
In "lib" folder of your project should be file android-support-v4.jar.

If not, firstly download it through your SDK Manager

Comment: I don't think that this is necessary since ActionBarSherlock already contains the compatibility library. If the compatibility library is imported, it will cause resource conflicts.

Comment: Thats why I asked you is there Android support library in Build Path. The error is self explanatory, there is no any import. BTW thx for the downvote

Comment: Uhm... I'm not the one who downvoted your answer. When I set the project to use ActionBarSherlock, won't the Android compatibility library be automatically included on the project since I'm assuming it's already inside the ActionBarSherlock jar? I already added the compatibility jar to the demo project so now the demo project contains both the ABS and the compatibility library. It's now working. But why is the compatibility required when it's already inside ABS? Can please explain it?

Comment: From the FAQ on their site "Do I need to include the .jar file for the Android compatibility library when using ActionBarSherlock?" ->" Yes. ActionBarSherlock is built as an extension of the Android compatibility library and requires that it be included." And all library files always must be added through the Build Path, simply copy jar to lib folder its wrong.